# Move my RingCentral account from sandbox environment to production environment

Tags: sandbox, production-environment, ringcentral

We are facing the issue in completing the graduation requirements due to the Read Call Recording permission, For completing the permission we have to execute the call recording [API that is](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/accountId/recording/recordingId)

in the URL recordingId is coming in the call Log [URL](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/672573005/extension/672573005/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2021-01-05T11:46:00.000Z&showDeleted=false&page=1&perPage=100) i.e. But it has an empty record so in that case, we have an issue to complete graduation requirements, we are something in a deadlock situation so please us to move sandbox to production

Answer (score 0):

For pushing your app into graduation you need to contact RingCentral developer support teat at devsupport at ringcentral.com or a support ticket [here](https://support.ringcentral.com/contact-support.html)
They can assist you with your graduation issue.